# node js link commands running error

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

i am creating node commands using node bin object from package.json but those are failed to execute due to microsoft javascript run time. how to point node environment

```
{ 
"name": "test",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
 bin":{
"runMy":"index.js"
 },
 "author": "",
"license": "ISC"
}
```

index.js file  have console.log("Happi")..

i used npm link command to "link" command to link the commands globally.

When i am running the "runMy" command i am getting following microsoft error 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did [my post below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879702/node-js-link-commands-running-error/39880730#39880730) answer your question? If it did then you may consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) because right now other people searching for this problem see that your question has no good answer accepted by you. If it didn't answer your question then please comment on what is missing. I'm going through my old answers and I want to update them if they need improvements. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try few things that may solve the problem. I don't have Windows to test it but here's what you can try:

First, make sure to add a shebang line as the first line of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

So the script would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log("Happi");
```

Note that there is no space or anything before the shebang line - the "#" hash character is the first character of the file.

That line is not used by the Windows system - it is used on Unix-like systems - but the Node's cmd-shim should install a correct wrapper on Windows when it sees that line.

I am not sure if running `npm link` is enough or running `npm install ...` to install that module is needed for the cmd-shim to take effect.

The other thing you may try is to change:

```
"runMy": "index.js"
```

to:

```
"runMy": "node index.js"
```

This should work in the "scripts" section in package.json. I'm not sure if that will work in the "bin" section.

There is also a wrap-cmd module that should let you wrap your script manually, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/wrap-cmd

And last, you can write your own .cmd or .bat file that would run "node your-script.js". An example.bat file could look like:

```
@echo off
node c:\path\to\your_program.js
```

It should work as long as you have node in your PATH.